# lightweight-charts: timeScale() changes visibleRange on setData()

Tags: javascript, lightweight-charts

I need to load data until it fills the visible area. But on `setData` the graph changes the visible area, which leads to endless data loading. It looks something like this https://jsfiddle.net/beholderrk/916g3tcf/3/

Is there any way to setData did not lead to a shift in the visible region of `timeScale()`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a bug when you set data via `setData` and the library moves visible range and I think that it shouldn't do it (it should work the same as if you have the last bar visible). I'd suggest you [file an issue on github](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md&title=) so we can mark it as a bug and fix in future versions.

Comment: Thanks. https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/549

Answer (score -1):

I have [forked the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9gu7zo4/) with what I think you want to achieve. You just need to add:

```
chart.applyOptions({
  priceScale:{
    autoScale: false,
  }
})
```

after the declaration. I also added a commented section in case you want to change the price scale:

```
// To set a different scale
  /*autoscaleInfoProvider: () => ({
    priceRange: {
      minValue: 170,
      maxValue: 300,
    },
  }),*/
```

I did not find any condition where the animation stops, though. Only when you press the `stop` button. You would need to add that part.

Comment: Thx for answer. I want the `timeScale` not move to the right when `setData`. autoScale changes behaviour of `priceScale`, not `timeScale`